# Is it possible to launch Word 365 in a browser from a web app to edit documents regardless whether the user has an office 365 license?

Tags: visual-studio, ms-word, office365, microsoft-graph-api

My local school allows me to log in to their online portal and access an email account using Outlook 365 within the browser, despite the fact I do not have a license for outlook/office 365.

Is it possible to create a web application where users of this app could click a link to edit a document directly in their browser using Word 365, with us/the developers of such app being the licensee of Word and not the end-user?  The remote document would be held in a Sharepoint/Webdav capable service.

If this is possible, which MS-technologies should we investigate to develop such a system?  Is it the MS-Graph API or something else?

A pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share the code which you have already tried and point out specific parts of the code where you are having problems

Comment: haven't tried any code yet as I'm asking a concept question and the answer is vital to whether to use those API's or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph to create a sharing link to a document. But the user will have to sign in to view the document I believe. I'm not sure what licensing they need but you can try this with your users to see.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Looks like the resource must reside in sharepoint/onedrive.  It'd be nice if this could be used to create a sharing link to documents on any webdav capable url so the documents could remain at the customer site.

Comment: David. I'm in the Graph team, and not entirely familiar with webdav capable url. where can a document live for that to work? e.g. where outside of OneDrive or SharePoint?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for your input.   We've been allowing our users of our web application to edit word documents directly in word (local installations).  Their Word application opens the document with a click of a link in our page, and saving transparantly saves the document back to the server without the need of saving locally, then uploading etc.  This happens thanks to WebDav, the protocol which is almost a successor to HTTP, as it introduces new verbs which Word uses in order to perform it's functions correctly, locking the document whilst editing for example.

Comment: I've never really read too much into Sharepoint,  but I believe when it was at least initially introduced,  it also was based on webdav.

Comment: So I was curious whether word 365 could also be used to open documents on a remote URL, like we do now with desktop installations of word.  Not just open the documents but programatically be controlled to launch and open documents, with licensing being handled at a higher level,  without the end user needing an individual license.  Like what appears to happening in the opening question where the school provides outlook to parents of the students without any individual licenses having to acquired by the end users.

Comment: This question is not really a developer question but more functionality of Word. I tried to find someone in Redmond thorugh contacts but couldn't find anyone. You may have more like in the End User forums. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-Apps/ct-p/OfficeApps1

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Google Docs API to work with documents stored in Google Drive. If you are using Java there is a "Quickstart" at the following link:

https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/java

Comment: Thanks Tim ,But I was asking what if the docs were NOT stored on Drive will still be possible !?